# My External USB drive stops after reading some data

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I had the external USB 3.0 western Digital My Book essential 3TB drive.

I had loto of data on it.

Suddenlt when i start copying data from it then after reading 20GB or so data then i get error that system can't read from the location.

I have to turn the uSB power off , disconnect it and then again connect it. so i have to trnasfer the data in small chunks like 20Gb , 30GB etc.

I have n ow transferred all the data but i want to know that is hard disk gone or it can be fixed or its something windows fault not HD fault

Comment: How old is the drive? If it has extensive use, and fairly old, it may due for replacement. Use WD HDD Diagnostic tools to test if the HDD is still in good condition or not -> http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en

Comment: drive is not very old , only about 1 year old and not very intensive use

Comment: @user191542 errors are not a good sign use a S.M.A.R.T tool on it.

Comment: @user191542 Current recommendation is to get your data out (which you have done - good), and use the WD HDD test and see what it said. If it failed any of the testing, and it is only 1 year old, chances are it is still under warranty, and send it back to WD. If it passes all test, I still won't trust the HDD for "only backup". Maybe as 2nd copy of your backup.